# Setting a cell in Numbers with AppleScript is broken

Tags: applescript

I have an AppleScript that's been working for several years that I use to populate a Numbers spreadsheet.  It's suddenly stopped working and I can't figure out why.  The line in question that fails is

```
set row newSalesRow's cell cellColumn's value to newValue
```

If I insert numbers for newSalesRow, cellColumn, and newValue it still crashes at that line.  I tried

```
set cell cellColumn of row newSalesRow to newValue
```

but it also fails.  The AppleScript error code is

"-1708: The script doesn’t understand the  message. The event was not handled.".

Answer (score 0):

After trying a number of different approaches and getting nowhere for several hours, I restarted Numbers. The problem disappeared.  Very frustrating.  Thanks for looking at the problem.